# Are Alexa skill dates the same in the Service Simulator and the Echo?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, timezone, alexa-skills-kit

My Alexa node.js skill involves getting the current date using "new Date()".  In the Service Simulator the date returned is UTC.  But I need the time in "America/New_York" -- my skill is local to New York.  So I can convert the time zone, no problem.  But I'm wondering whether this will get the same result when I deploy the skill.  That is, does the Date() function on the actual Service convert to local time from UTC?  If it does, then I will need some way of determining in my code whether I am in the Service Simulator or the actual Service, and converting to New York time in my accordingly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for Date

> If no arguments are provided, the constructor creates a JavaScript Date object for the current date and time according to system settings.

So depending on the system settings the timezones can be different.
To overcome this you can use UTC date everywhere and then simply convert the timezone where needed.

```
// date with some timezone depending on system
let date = new Date();

// date in UTC
let utcDate = new Date(date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth(), date.getUTCDate(), date.getUTCHours(), date.getUTCMinutes(), date.getUTCSeconds());
```

Note: utcDate will still be in the system timezone, but the actual value it holds will represent the correct date and time in UTC.

Comment: Do you know if there is any way to change the time zone system settings in the service simulator?

Comment: No, the simulator will always return time in UTC, but an actual device will give you information about the timezone it belongs to.
More info [here](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/4724/amazondate-slot-type-seems-to-be-inherently-broken.html)

Comment: My skill is now live, and on the echo it is returning UTC instead of my local time (Eastern US).  However if I just ask Alexa the time it is returning the correct local time.  So does this mean I need to convert UTC to local time in my lambda function?